# How to recover after removing only LUKS key?

Tags: fedora, hard-disk, luks, disk-encryption

In a stupid attempt to disable LUKS encryption, I have done

```
cryptsetup luksRemoveKey
```

to my only key. So now everytime I try to boot my Fedora-21, it asks for the passphrase but obviously does not recognize it, and says

```
Reached target System Initialization
Reached target Basic System
```

and that's it. Is there a way to recover from this or I have to reformat my hard disk?

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey
```

doesn't seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 6):

As the man page states, it's game over.

> Removing the last passphrase makes the LUKS container permanently
>   inaccessible.

That is, if you really removed the last key. Does `cryptsetup luksDump` show `DISABLED` for all key slots?

Normally `cryptsetup` prevents you from doing that, or at least asks for confirmation:

```
# cryptsetup luksRemoveKey foobar
Enter passphrase to be deleted: 

WARNING!
========
This is the last keyslot. Device will become unusable after purging this key.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): NO, ABSOLUTELY NOT OKAY!
```

It does that unless it's in batch mode or reads the passphrase from a pipe.

Personally I feel it should prevent you even then, after all if you really wanted to make it inaccessible you could just as well use `luksErase` directly. But that's not how it seems to work.

It would be a different story if you either had a backup of the LUKS header, or if the LUKS container was still open. The backup of the LUKS header you could just restore or use with `luksOpen --header thebackup.header`.

For an open LUKS container, you could obtain the master key with `dmsetup table --showkeys` and build a new LUKS header out of that as shown in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178722/30851) (it obtains the master key a different way but it's the same concept).

Comment: This does not work with a mounted volume though - so if its your / mounted volume that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`cryptsetup` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/cryptsetup.8.html):

> Removing the last passphrase makes the LUKS container permanently inaccessible.

That's an inherent property of the design of LUKS. Each key slot contains the actual encryption key, wrapped by a key derived from the passphrase. If there is no slot left containing a wrapped key, then there is no copy of the key anymore.

I'm afraid you'll have to restore your data from a backup.