# How to modify -iter-time on a existing luks partition

Tags: debian, grub2, grub, luks, cryptsetup

first of all I already read this topic :
[How to change the hash-spec and iter-time of an existing dm-crypt LUKS device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101343/how-to-change-the-hash-spec-and-iter-time-of-an-existing-dm-crypt-luks-device)

where the proposal is the following command :

```
cryptsetup-reencrypt --keep-key
```

However, the answer is 7 years ago and was considered as experimental. On my side, I have installed Debian from a live USB ticking on *encrypt Disk* during install. So when I boot my device, I have to decrypt directly from grub. It takes too long to decrypt because it seems that default `--iter-time` is around 30 seconds even if my password is correct, therefore some people propose to reduce `--iter-time` to `300`.

This is why I have additional questions :

1. Is `cryptsetup-reencrypt --keep-key -iter-time DEVICE` the exact correct code today ?
2. The partition which has Luks over it is `/dev/nvme0n1p2` and the luks partition is `/dev/mapper/luks-xxxx`, there is also the same for the swap partition. Which device to chose : `cryptsetup-reencrypt --keep-key -iter-time /dev/nvme0n1p2` or `cryptsetup-reencrypt --keep-key -iter-time /dev/mapper/luks-xxxx` ?
3. Shall I use it from command in grub menu or from a live USB ?
4. Is it formatting my data ? (better asking twice)

Thank you very much.

**FYI :**

- *OS :* Debian
- *Way of installing Luks :* by live USB (just ticking "encrypt disk")
- *LUKS version :* LUKS 1
- *SLOTS :* Key Slots 0 & 1 enabled, key slots 2 to 7 disabled

Comment: Grub is slower than `cryptsetup` can't really help it if you don't provide unencrypted `/boot`... LUKS 1 or LUKS 2? `cryptsetup luksDump`?

Comment: Hello, I have edited my first post so you can see which luks I use. Please, feel free to help me, thank you very much !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to reencrypt the device if you want to change only `--iter-time`. Reencryption is used when you want to change the way the data on the disk is encrypted (so different key, algorithm or, in case of the linked question, hash function). Iteration time is a "property" of the key slot -- it tells how long should [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) take when derivating the key from your passphrase. To change it you need to change only the key slot property with

```
cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/nvme0n1p2 --iter-time <time in ms>
```

It will ask for passphrase and change properties of key slot with that passphrase, it is possible to select key slot for the operation with `--key-slot` (if you have same passphrase for multiple key slots). You'll need to repeat this if you want to change the iteration time for both key slots.

(This will also ask you to change your password, you can just reuse your old one, `luksConvertKey` which only changes the parameters doesn't work with LUKS 1.)

You can check the result with `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/nvme0n1p2` you should see the number PBKDF iterations decreased.

Comment: Thank you very much Vojtech Trefny, this worked ! For other people like me, please note that it worked the second try, not the first one (I have 2 slots, therefore, I imagine Luks has decreased the wrong one the first time).

Comment: also, please note that I have tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation to do so, I am really sorry for that (I have marked the answer as solved anyway), I hope other people will upvote your kindness !